# How do you automount additional pools with a zfs root?

Tags: automount, 19.10, zfs

In looking through all the older advice on this, it appears that everything no longer implies, such as enabling `zfs-import.service`:

```
# systemctl enable zfs-import.service
Synchronizing state of zfs-import.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable zfs-import
Failed to enable unit: Unit file /lib/systemd/system/zfs-import.service is masked.
```

As zfs support has clearly changed with this release, what is the appropriate way to auto-mount not just the root (which is working fine) but additional pools?

Answer (score 0):

*workaround*

This workaround is inspired by this [link](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/3170), the solution had to be adjusted to work with the cron daemon version as follows:

Added the following line in /etc/crontab

```
@reboot root zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id <pool-name> >> /dev/null
# ex.: @reboot root zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id tank/videos >> /dev/null
```

There are so many posts on the internet raising the same issue for different Ubuntu or (even other Linux) distributions.

It took me weeks to find this workaround as all proposed solutions didn't work for me.

Again, it's only a "workaround" until a formal solution is developed given the current status of zfs on linux in general and it's "experimental" status on Ubuntu 19.10 in specific.

Comment: Thanks for providing input on this.  One of the issues is that the mounts may not be done in an appropriate order.  As an example, I have a zfs mount for my docker instances, and depending on which services comes up first, this may or may not mount before the mount point is "in use".  A similar situation exists for libkvm vm instances.  I suspect the answer will be to create a systemd service script that will mount the appropriate mounts in the proper order, so as to provide a fixed mount time.

Comment: Correct. That's definitely the better "workaround" in order to control when mounting happens. I just wanted to give back a quick way to auto mount on reboot (as it took me so long to figure it out), until a standard and usable way for auto mounting of zfs is released.